What is [] in a struct pointer?
I'm trying to use a callback function in C and I got into this piece of code:
memcpy(&(mem->response[mem->size]), data, realsize);

I understand everything except this part :
&(mem->response[mem->size]

I understand that we're trying to get the address of mem but what is [] in this context ?

If mem->response is a pointer to an array of elements, then
mem->response[mem->size]

refers to the element at position mem->size in that array and & is used to get a pointer to that element.
You get the same result with mem->response + mem->size if that makes it clearer:
memcpy(mem->response + mem->size, data, realsize);


Thank's i was dumb, it was a char array ;)

@Yuki You're welcome! Easy mistake to make. :-)

that:
&(mem->response[mem->size])

can be fully parenthesized as:
&((*mem).(response[(*mem).size]))

which means the address of the mem->size element of the array reponse field of the value pointed to by mem, so

mem is a pointer to a struct or union which has at least two fields (size and response)  being the first of integer type, and the second an array or a pointer to some data, organized as an array.
mem->size should be of an integer type to indicate an array position.
response is an array of at least mem->size + 1 elements of some type which adress is being obtained by the & operator.
mem is a pointer to a structure or union which has a field named response that is an array of which for some element its address is being evaluated by the expression.

But as you don't provide the type definitions of mem, and the structure of the value pointed, nor the response array, it is not possible to go further.
